# How to make a multi-module project in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, intellij-idea

How would you make a multi module project in IntelliJ 11 IDEA? I have made a IntelliJ project where I add new Maven modules, but I am unable to put one Maven module inside another so they have the same physical layout as they does in logic (parent/child).

Is this possible? Or should it be done?

I only get all modules on the same level in the physical directory structure.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what do you mean. I open a root pom of a multi-module maven project where submodules are in subdirectories. This gives me equivalent hierarchical layout in Idea.

Comment: So you make your projects through CLI instead of inside the IDEA?

Comment: Yes, initially I edit my poms manually to create structure, then open it with Idea.

Comment: Ah, okey. I will try it out when I am home. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a listbox in Project view that is called "View as".
Select "Project".

Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Bob - So the maven projects are structured, but they reside in same directory level in the file system?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering about best practice: Should these modules be in the same directory level in the file system when there is a parent project, or should these modules be inside the parent project?